# Visual Studio Online - Administrator Reset

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

My company has its project configured to a VS Team services setup by one of the contractor who used his personal Enterprise subscription.

The contractor is now riding bikes in mountain and we are not expecting him to come back, can I get an advise on my options now?

Do I need to buy Enterprise Subscription for VS which cost around $2999, that gives me >5 VS licenses and VS Team services for managing project repositories in cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Team Services doesn't require you to have an MSDN subscription. The 5 free users are included in the Team Services account itself, but you can purchase additional users for circa $4 per user per month. You may need to have the Visual Studio Team Services Subscription linked to a different Azure subscription, these can be created independently of an MSDN subscription. Most features are available as part of the Basic account, and some additional features, like Test Management and Release Management, require an additional licence. Everything is included in MSDN Enterprise, most is included in MSDN Premium, and the basics are included in MSDN Professional. You can purchase all of the features you use independently of MSDN.

To change the Owner of the account you will need to Contact support by scrolling down to the Contact Us box on the Visual Studio Team Services:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/

You may need to hand over proof you are the original owner and may need to have the current owner participate in the hand-off, even of he's cycling in the mountains.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comment, I have now created a VSTS account online and I have created a project also which I can now develop using VS. Just one more thing, with VSTS free, I still have to buy 5 separate Visual Studio 2015 Professional license? VS Code is free but I am looking for VS Professional version.

Comment: Correct. Unless you fit the Visual Studio Community Edition requirements, in which case you can use that for free => https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547